# add condition in name option select with loop array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello I would like to put a condition on the name of the option if the object `sku.attributes` is empty the name is same product otherwise it displays the color and size

```
skusListProduct = [{attributes:{size:'m', color: 'black'}}] // ex array
            <select
              v-model="skuList"
              @change="productChoice"
            >
              <option
                v-for="sku in skusListProduct"
                :key="sku.id"
                :value="sku.id"
              >
                <span v-if="sku.attributes && sku.attributes.length > 0">
                  {{ sku.attributes.color }} {{ sku.attributes.size }}
                </span>
                <span v-else>
                  same product
                </span>
              </option>
            </select>
```

I'm do that but is doesn't work

Comment: Read your question 5 times and still do not understand what your question is and what is happing.

Comment: @FerryKranenburg I'm edit my question

Comment: The way to clarify this question is to show a few of the objects in the `skuListProduct` array, including thise with and without `attributes` prop.

Comment: Looks fine. Post example of array itself and component?

Comment: @FerryKranenburg I'm edit my question i had example of array

Answer (score 0):

I'm resolve my answer check if keys sku.attributes is exist

`sku.attributes && Object.keys(sku.attributes).length > 0`